# No wi-fi networks found after Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: 14.04

My laptop is Acer Aspire 5 (Model A515-51-563W). It is running on Windows 10 and everything works fine. Recently, I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop for my research. This Ubuntu is running along with my Windows, that means, I have setup a dual boot. The problem is that I did not find any wi-fi connection when I log into Ubuntu OS, though I am running several wi-fi networks perfectly in my Windows system. I went to ubuntu Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers, but it said "No additional drivers available". What shall I do now to get back the wi-fi networks?

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I ran the script you have posted here, but after running it, it shows the error message "Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com' "

What should I do now?

Comment: It works for me. Do you have a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible?

Comment: No, I don't have any ethernet or tethered connection right now.  In case of no-connection, what I have to do?